# Read an excel file from encrypted disk partition into R

Tags: r, macos

I have created an encrypted disk on my macbookpro. I would like to open an excel file from this drive (I have the password of course) and load it into R. Is this possible? Or do I have to move the file onto, for example, my desktop and then load it into R?

Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to do so, but you mount the partition and give R permission. Then you have access to your files at will.

Comment: I can mount it, but I'm not sure how to give R permission and what the file paths to point to my data would be. Thanks btw!

Comment: can you go into the partition and use info to get the file path once it is mounted? That may be enough if you set the directory to point to the folder from there...

Comment: How was this "encrypted disk" created? What sort of file is it really? How would you mount it in your OS from a bash console or from the Finder or from Disk Utility? If it is a disk image then why would moving it to the Desktop be helpful? (This does not appear to be specific to "mecbookpro", so replaced with the more generic OS tag.)

Comment: I used the Disk Utility to encrypt a folder I had created. The encrypted folder contains excel files (.xlsx) which I am now trying to access from R. I can mount it by double clicking the folder in Finder and entering the password. When I said "move it to the Desktop" I meant move the .xlsx files to the Desktop and out of the encrypted disk, where they are easily accessible by R. I would prefer not to do that, and access the files from R in their present location.